# iTerm2 shows some number on terminal

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I am using iTerm2+zsh and this is how my terminal looks
[image]

Now if you look there are these numbers with mathematical operators `*4 +3 !2`.
Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What do you mean by _resolve_? This is obviously produced by your prompt (`PS1`), but it is up to you how you define your prompt, and you can modify it as you like.

Comment: I am talking about these numbers `*4 +3 !2` don't know why are those there

Comment: They are obviously also part of the prompt.That's why I said, I would first of all analyse the `PS1`.

Comment: It's information about your Git repository. Probably something like 4 untracked files, 2 modified files, and your local branch is 3 commits ahead of the remote branch it tracks.

Comment: Well, that is something I can correlate it to now. Can you help me in showing some icons instead? What settings to change.

Answer (score 0):

You have likely installed [Powerlevel9k](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k) or [Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k).

`*4` means 4 stashes

`+3` means 3 staged changes

`!2` means 2 unstaged changes

See [What do different symbols in Git status mean?](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean) for details.